# Converting a text file into a list of lists

Tags: python, list

I want to convert a text file in the format:

```
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
0,1,0,0,0,0,0,
0,2,0,0,0,0,0,
0,2,0,1,0,0,0,
2,1,0,2,1,0,0,
1,1,0,1,2,1,0,
```

into a list of lists. However, all I can get is:

```
`[['0,0,0,0,0,0,0,'],
 ['0,1,0,0,0,0,0,'],
 ['0,2,0,0,0,0,0,'],
 ['0,2,0,1,0,0,0,'],
 ['2,1,0,2,1,0,0,'],
 ['1,1,0,1,2,1,0,']]`
```

But I don't want the quotation marks around the lists. Any help?

my code is:

```
while z!=0:
    y.append([f.readline().rstrip('\n')])
    z-=1
```

Comment: You have quotation mark because they are string, you need ints to not have marks

Answer (score 1):

You need to read each line, split by comma, and parse each value to `int`

```
values = []
with open("data.txt") as fic:
    for line in fic:
        line = line.rstrip(",\r\n")  
        row = list(map(int, line.split(",")))
        values.append(row)

# same as 
with open("data.txt") as fic:
    values = [list(map(int, line.rstrip(",\r\n").split(","))) for line in fic]
```

Gives you

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 [0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 [0, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], 
 [2, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0], 
 [1, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
y.append([int(n) for n in f.readline().rstrip('\n').split(',')[:-1]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this inside the while loop :

```
y.append([int(i) for i in f.readline().rstrip('\n').split(',') if i])
```